# Implicitly and explicitly defined columns in CSS

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

I was doing an online quiz about [CSS grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_grid_layout), and I was confused by one of the problems.

Here's the problem:

> Imagine we have a grid with the following CSS properties, with 4 boxes inside of it. If we added a fifth box to the HTML, what width would it have?

And here's the code:

```
.grid {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 100px);
  grid-auto-rows: 60px;
  grid-auto-columns: 70px;
 }
```

My thought was: so there are already four boxes, if we were to add a new one, it would trigger the 'grid-auto-rows' and 'grid-auto-columns'. So its width would be 70 pixels.

But the answer says that:

> The new box will still be in one of the explicitly defined columns, which are 100 pixels each.

Why would the new box be in one of the explicitly defined columns? Isn't there already four inside and it's fully occupied?

Answer (score 1):

The width of your fifth item is indeed 100px, as defined by `grid-template-columns`.

*Here's why:*

The initial four boxes create a 2x2 grid, as you have defined in the grid container:

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 100px);
  grid-auto-rows: 60px;
  grid-auto-columns: 70px;
}

section {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: .9em;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <section>100 x 50</section>
  <section>100 x 50</section>
  <section>100 x 50</section>
  <section>100 x 50</section>
</article>
```

Then you add a fifth item. This item falls outside the explicit grid area.

At this point you need to factor in the [**`grid-auto-flow`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow) property.

This property controls the placement of grid items that are not explicitly placed (aka, "auto-placed items").

It's default value is `row`, which means that auto-placed items are laid out row by row, filling each row, and adding new rows as necessary.

Because your grid container is defaulting to `grid-auto-flow: row`, and all explicit rows are filled, **a new row is created in the implicit grid to accommodate the fifth item**.

The fifth item ends up on Column 1, Row 3.

Column 1 already exists. It was created by `grid-template-columns` and has a 100px width.

Row 3 is new and implicit. Its height is 60px, as defined in `grid-auto-rows`.

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 100px);
  grid-auto-rows: 60px;
  grid-auto-columns: 70px;
}

/* non-essential demo styles */
section {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: .9em;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <section>100 x 50</section>
  <section>100 x 50</section>
  <section>100 x 50</section>
  <section>100 x 50</section>
  <section>100 x&nbsp;<b>60</b></section>  
</article>
```

If instead you used `grid-auto-flow: column`, then auto-placed items would flow vertically, filling up columns and creating new ones as necessary. Then your fifth item would be 70px wide.

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 100px);
  grid-auto-rows: 60px;
  grid-auto-columns: 70px;
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* new */
}

/* non-essential demo styles */
section {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: .9em;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <section>100 x 50</section>
  <section>100 x 50</section>
  <section>100 x 50</section>
  <section>100 x 50</section>
  <section><b>70</b>&nbsp;x 50</section>  
</article>
```